# How do I have multiple app manifests for a single code base for different clients?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have a Windows Store App that I want to be able to brand and publish to the store for many different clients as there app, what is the best way to do this keeping the same code base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ways to keep the same code base. Which is best probably depends on how much customisation you want to do for each client and how much of that customisation is data driven.

1. Put as much of the code as possible in a library and include that in the various apps
2. Link the same file(s) into the projects for each app
3. If only your assets are different then you can create a master project and a script to duplicate it and replace the assets, IDs, etc.
4. Similar to 3, use a pre-build step to copy the client-specific data into the project.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the reply. It will only be the assets / app name that will change between clients. Would you recommend step 3 or 4?

Comment: You'll have to decide for yourself. In general I'd choose #1 first, then I'd probably explore #4.